# Populate foreign key ID from two seperate primary key IDs - postgres SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables, penn_survey and panama_survey, that connect to a VES table with both being a one too many relationship. The below query will populate the 'multi_survey_id' column, f.key to both survey tables. The query will populate correctly for one table. However, when I run the second query to connect the second survey table and populate the 'multi_survey_id' again for the second survey table it deletes the IDs from the first survey table in the 'multi_survey_id' column.

How do I preserve the first set of 'multi_survey_ids'?

```
-- VES: add unique ID, p.key, join id on site/date/survey_time/detection_type, and create f.key     
alter table ves 
add column ves_id UUID default (public.uuid_generate_v4());

alter table ves 
add primary key(ves_id);

alter table ves 
add column mult_survey_id UUID;

alter table ves 
alter column "date" type date using ("date"::text::date);

--------- VES to panama_survey
update ves v 
set mult_survey_id = 
    (select ps.panama_survey_id
    from panama_survey ps
    where (ps.site, ps."date", ps.survey_time, ps.detection_type) = (v.site, v."date", v.survey_time, v.detection_type));
    
--------- VES to penn_survey
update ves v 
set mult_survey_id =
    (select pes.penn_survey_id
    from penn_survey pes
    where (pes.site, pes."date", pes.survey_time, pes.detection_type) = (v.site, v."date", v.survey_time, v.detection_type));
```

Comment: why an update and not an insert, your concept looks wrong please add data to your tables (all) and show what you are trying to do, my gut twells me you want an INSERt and **not** an UPDATE

Comment: I am working adding the data. Do you have input as the best approach how to show the data for postges examples? I only know of dput() within r. I think I am close with the insert statement. I want to insert the 'panama_survey_id' from the 'panama_survey' table into the 'multi_survey_id' column in the 'ves' table when site, date, survey_time, and detection_type equal each other ```insert into ves (multi_survey_id)
 (select ps.panama_survey_id
 from panama_survey ps
 where (ps.site, ps."date", ps.survey_time, ps.detection_type) = (v.site, v."date", v.survey_time, v.detection_type));```

Comment: an insert should only be made when the data is different, an update is made when you have one row that needs changes.

Comment: great thank you for this tidbit of info. New to postgres

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by incorporating "is null" to the second update

```
--------- VES to panama_survey
update ves v 
set mult_survey_id = 
    (select ps.panama_survey_id
    from panama_survey ps
    where (ps.site, ps."date", ps.survey_time, ps.detection_type) = (v.site, v."date", v.survey_time, v.detection_type));
    
    
--------- VES to penn_survey
update ves v 
set  mult_survey_id =
    (select pes.penn_survey_id
    from penn_survey pes
    where (pes.site, pes."date", pes.survey_time, pes.detection_type) = (v.site, v."date", v.survey_time, v.detection_type))
where mult_survey_id is null;
```

Through this though I found you can not have multiple f.keys in the same column. So for now I have created two separate columns for f.keys from each unique survey table.